# React MERN App - Not passing ID to fetch api

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks, mern

I am creating a react app with full crud functionality. It allows users to create job postings and i wanted to click on a specific job to view more details.

I am having trouble as everytime i try to click a "job" it says that ID is undefined specifically:
**show function called with id: undefined**
**SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input**

My app currently displays the list of all jobs and creates.

I already confirmed the following:

Made sure the backend server is running and listening on port 3001.
Verified that the endpoint i am trying to fetch actually exists. Tried on postman
Made sure that my frontend code is using the correct URL to make requests to the backend.

I am using hooks and functions.

DetailsPage.js

```
import styles from './DetailsPage.module.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import jobsService from '../../utils/jobsService';

export default function DetailPage(props) {
  const [job, setJob] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const { id } = props.match?.params || {};

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await jobsService.show(id);
        setJob(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <div className={styles.list}>
          <div className={styles.Grid}>

            <h3>{job.title}</h3>
            <p>{job.description}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

jobsService.js

```
async function getAll(){
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/jobs')
    const data = await response.json()
    return data
}   
async function create(item) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/jobs/create', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(item)
      });
      return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
  }

async function show(id) {
    console.log("show function called with id:", id);
    return fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/jobs/${id}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then(res => res.json());
  }
  
  

   
  
  

export default {
    getAll,
    create,
    show,
}
```

Comment: Make sure the json file is syntactically correct. GET the file as text/plain to see what is comming from server...

Answer (score 0):

destruct id form empty object ?

instead this

```
const { id } = props.match?.params || {};
```

test this

```
const { id } = props.match?.params || {id: 0};
```

or use ternary operator in function calling
or

```
async function show(id = 0) {
    console.log("show function called with id:", id);
    return fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/jobs/${id}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then(res => res.json());
  }
```